# How to show only hidden directories, and then find hidden files separately

Tags: ls, dot-files

I'm trying to list all the hidden files in a directory, but not other directories, and I am trying to do this using only ls and grep.

```
ls -a | egrep  "^\."
```

This is what I have so far, but the problem is that it also lists hidden directories, when I don't want that.

Then, completely separately, I want to list the hidden directories.

Comment: why not to use `find`?? why to limit self w/ `ls` and `grep`??

Comment: just for the case (if you don't know about `find`):
1) `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -type f` to find "hidden" files
2)  `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -type d` to find "hidden" directories

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To list only **hidden files**:

```
ls -ap | grep -v / | grep "^\."
```

Note that *files* here is everything that is not a directory. It's not file in *"everything in Linux is a file"* ;)

To list only **hidden directories**:

```
ls -ap | grep "^\..*/$"
```

**Comments:**

- `ls -ap` lists everything in the current directory, including hidden
  ones, and puts a `/` at the end of directories.
- `grep -v /` inverts results of `grep /`, so that no directory is included.
- `"^\..*/$"` matches everything that start with `.` and end in `/`.
- If you want to exclude `.` and `..` directories from results of the second part, you can use `-A` option instead of `-a` for `ls`, or if you like to work with regex, you can use `"^\.[^.]+/$"` instead of `"^\..*/$"`.

Have fun!

Comment: Whilst the others did answer the question, you were the only one who listened when I said I only wanted to use ls and grep. I know you can do this using find, but I wanted to be able to do this using only grep and ls, thanks a lot

Comment: Try `ls -aF` instead of `ls -ap`

Comment: `ls -aF | egrep "^\.[^.]+/$" | tar -zcvf hiddens.tar.gz -T -` doesn't seem to do the trick. It creates an empty archive.

Comment: Good answer. Just a note: I don't think there is any reason to use
`egrep` instead of normal `grep` in this case. Also,
[direct invocation as [...] `egrep` [...] is deprecated](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html).
As phrased in the official
[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/)
document:
[this _grep_ has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical _egrep_ and _fgrep_ commands as well.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).

Answer (score 6):

To list the hidden files and directories in the current directory, including . and ..:

```
echo .*
```

To list the hidden files and directories in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively:

```
find . -name '.*'
```

If you want to save the results to a file, use a redirection:

```
find . -name '.*' >output-file.txt
```

Comment: `echo .[!.]*` or `echo .[^.]*`will list the hidden files and directories, **excluding `.` and `..`**

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `zsh` (if you haven't already), and run

```
ls .*(^/)
```

The part inside parenthesis is so called glob qualifiers and means to select everything but directories.

If you are interested only in plain files, so want to exclude not only directories, but also other special files (named pipes etc) then try

```
ls .*(.)
```

Answer (score 1):

To list hidden files (long list extensive format)

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -ls | sed 's/^..//'
```

To list directories (a long format)

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -ls | sed 's/^..//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' | sed 's/^..//'
```

This will find only files (-type f) in the current directory (-maxdepth 1), starting with a '.', the sed command gets rid of './' in every line.

Answer (score 0):

List files:

```bash
tree --prune -aiL 1 -P .[^.]\* path/to/dir
```

List directories:

```bash
tree -daiL 1 -I [^.]\* path/to/dir
```

The first line displays the checked directory, and the last line displays the report. However, the report can be disabled with adding the `--noreport` flag.
`path/do/dir` - If this parameter is omitted, the current directory `.` is used.

Answer (score -2):

This command works:

```
ls -a | grep ".*"
```

- Any hidden file starts with `.`
- `*` matches all characters

Comment: In this context, `.*` doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: The regular expression `.*` matches _any string_, not just string starting with a dot.

Comment: `"^.*"` matches all the patterns that start with `.`

Comment: @madD7 No, it matches any string that contains zero or more characters. To match a string that starts with a dot, use either `^\.` or `^[.]`.