# Tarring-gzipping only hidden directories (or files + directories)

Tags: regular-expression, directory, tar, gzip

Based on [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/tar-only-hidden-files-603340/), to tar all hidden files in the current directory one can use

`ls -A | egrep '^\.' | tar cvf ./test.tar -T -`

However, how can one tar only all hidden directories or all hidden directories and files in the current directory?

Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252165/how-to-show-only-hidden-directories-and-then-find-hidden-files-separately), `ls -ap | egrep "^\..*/$" | tar -zcvf hiddens.tar.gz -T -` should do the trick. Yet it does not. This command simply creates an empty tar.gz archive. So tar does not see any directories at all then by this command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `zsh`, to tar all hidden dirs (and their contents):

```
tar zcf file.tar.gz .*(/)
```

(note that the standard `.*/` is not the same as zsh's `.*(/)` as it would also include symlinks and with some `tar` implementations, because a `/` is appended to the paths resulting from the glob expansion, would tar them as directories (along with all their contents), not symlinks, so likely not what you want; see also the note below about `.` and `..` in many shells).

To tar hidden dirs and regular files:

```
tar zcf file.tar.gz .*(/,.)
```

To tar all hidden files regardless of their type (dirs, regular, symlinks, fifos...)

```
tar zcf file.tar.gz .*
```

That one would also work with the `fish` shell, or mksh or other shells based on the Forsyth shell, but not with most other shells as those other shells do include `.` and `..` in the expansion of that glob.

With `ksh93` however, you can do:

```
(FIGNORE='@(.|..)'; tar zcf file.tar.gz .*)
```

With `bash`:

```
(shopt -s dotglob failglob; tar zcf file.tar.gz [.]*)
```

Or with bash 5.2 or newer:

```
(shopt -s globskipdots failglob; tar zcf file.tar.gz .*)
```

(`globskipdots` causing `.` and `..` never to be returned in glob expansions, an option you'd likely want always enabled as having `.` and `..` included is never useful).

Comment: +1; It is worthwhile for bash users to learn how to use anonther shell or `shopt -s dotglob failglob` to make this task simple and reliable (and probably several other tasks too).

Answer (score 4):

It is often discouraged to use `ls` in shellscripts or complicated command lines because the results may be difficult to predict.

The following commands using `find` should work, when your current directory is your home directory, `~`,

```
cd ~
```

This command will only get the hidden files

```
LC_ALL=C find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.*' -print0 | tar --null -cvzf hidden-files.tar.gz -T -
```

This command will 'only' get the hidden directory trees (including subdirectories and files)

```
LC_ALL=C find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*' -print0 | tar --null -cvzf hidden-dirs.tar.gz -T -
```

Please notice that there might be unexpected results if you have symbolic links in the directory trees.

Comment: Parsing the output of `find -print` is discouraged for the same reason parsing the output of `ls` is discouraged: it's not post-processable reliably. The output of `find -print0` is post-processable reliably.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, should I add the option `-print0` into the commands? Or should I simply delete the answer because it is better that bash users learn to use `shopt -s dotglob failglob` ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Or is it OK to use `-exec ... +`

Comment: It's useful as it works even for large list of files and is likely more efficient. But yes, please change to use `-print0` (and corresponding tar option bearing in mind that like `-T`, that won't be a portable option).

Comment: ``-exec +` wouldn't work properly  if `find` ends up running `tar` several times because the list of files is big.

Comment: You'd also want to run `find` under `LC_ALL=C` or otherwise it would miss hidden files whose names can't be decoded as characters in the current locale.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, In order to make it waterproof, it is getting complicated. Learn anonther shell or `shopt -s dotglob failglob` is worthwhile for bash users.

Comment: @sudodus, while for interactive use the bash (or zsh) way is usually preferred, many systems default to lighter-weight shells for `/bin/sh` that are faster, so there is value in knowing the plain POSIX (almost; `-print0` is *not* POSIX, but should work basically everywhere it matters) way when writing scripts.